# Do I have to make another model to perform a Tukey test when the anova shows that only the factors are significant and not their interaction?

Tags: r, model, anova, tukey

I'm doing repeated measurements ANOVA in R with libraries:

```r
library(ordinal)
library(car)
library(RVAideMemoire)
```

I have two groups: months and distance and the dependent variable is CO2:

> distance  month     CO2
>
> 0 metres   july     234

I've made a clmm model for CO2 explained by distance, month and interaction betwee month and distance:

```
model_CO2 = clmm(CO2.f ~ month + distance + month:distance + (1|nest),
             data = field_data,
             threshold = "equidistant")
```

The results show that both month and distance are significan, but not there interaction.
Now, I want to perform a Tukey test with this information, so my idea is to perform a Tukey test for each factor separatedly.

My question is:

Do I have to make another model, where I separate each factor? Or can I just perform the Tukey test using the model I created but only considering one factor?

Example:

Using the initial model:

```
library(emmeans)
library(lsmeans)

Tmonth = lsmeans(model_CO2,
        ~ month)
multcomp::cld(Tmonth,
              alpha = 0.05,
              Letters = letters,
              adjust = "tukey")
```

Creating a new model only for month and then performing a Tukey test:

```
model_CO2m = clmm(CO2.f ~ month + (1|nest),
                 data = field_data,
                 threshold = "equidistant")
Tmonth = lsmeans(model_CO2m,
        ~ month)
multcomp::cld(Tmonth,
              alpha = 0.05,
              Letters = letters,
              adjust = "tukey")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: belongs on https://stats.stackexchange.com ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think some people would recommend that you do. But no, you don't *have* to, in that the estimated marginal means that you are comparing are well-defined; the interaction effects are just averaged over.

I would recommend that you plot the estimates for the factor combinations, though -- using `emmip()` for example -- so that you clearly understand what the estimates are that are being averaged.

### Note

I just noticed in the question that you took a factor completely out of the model. I definitely recommend *against* doing that. Each factor contributes a significant main effect, so they both belong in the model. If you are to consider a reduced model here, only consider the one with both main effects but no interaction.

Comment: PS -- I recommend against using cld. That display highlights NON-findings rather than findings. (When a difference is not significant, that does not imply hat there is no difference, just that you failed to prove there is one. In the extreme, when you have no data at all, everything is non-significant, but you have no proof of anything at all.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have any suggestions about what I can use?

Comment: Just report the P values for the pairwise comparisons. You might like pwpp() or pwpm() -- the latter requires the very latest version of emmeans

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that